# Combinations subject to constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Assume the following tree:

```
     g
   /   \
  e     f
 / \   / \
a   b c   d
```

I am having trouble determining if there is a way to calculate the combinations based on the following constraint:

Assume you must delete N points (a – g). You may only delete points with no children (i.e., at start, you may only delete a – d).
However, if you delete both children of a given node (i.e., a and b), you may delete it.

So, an example route you may take is:

1. Delete A: Remaining options == B, C, D.
2. Delete B: Remaining options == E, C, D.
3. Delete C: Remaining options == C, D.

I understand the combinations at the first point will be $\binom{4}{3}$, but that's about all I've got.

Comment: If you delete C, the remaining options should be D and E.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively calculate the generating function of the number of ways to delete $n$ points in a node's subtree. If a node is a leaf, $f_v(x) = 1+x$. Otherwise, $f_v = x^{\text{sz}(v)} + \prod_{c \text{ child of } v} f_c(x)$, because you can either take the entire tree of size $\text{sz}(v)$, or you can take some combination of choices from the children, which is expressed by the product.

For your example tree, due to its high symmetry, it can be calculated like this:

The nodes `a, b, c, d` have polynomial $1+x$

The nodes `e,f` have polynomial $(1+x)^2 + x^3 = 1 + 2x + x^2 + x^3$

The node `g` (and the entire tree) has polynomial $(1 + 2x + x^2 + x^3)^2 + x^7 = 1 + 4 x + 6 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 5 x^4 + 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^7$

So there is 1 way to remove $0$ nodes, $4$ to remove 1 node, $6$ to remove 2 nodes, $6$ to remove 3 nodes, $5$ to remove 4 nodes, $2$ to remove 5 nodes, $1$ to remove 6 nodes, and $1$ to remove 7 nodes.